# Default path for installed binary?

Tags: linux, fedora, vlc-media-player, yum

By doing

```
yum install vlc
```

I have installed the `vlc` player on my system. Now I want to know where the binary of `vlc` was installed. So what is the default path for installation in Fedora Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose

```
which vlc
```

will do the trick if the path the file was installed is on the System Path.

Answer (score 3):

This may be of help: [Unix Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)

Most binaries are installed in **/usr/bin**, most libs in **/usr/lib** and most headers - in **/usr/include**.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have installed vlc from a rpm package, you can use the rpm tool to query the database with information about all the installed packages:

```
$ rpm -ql vlc-core | grep '/vlc$'
/usr/bin/vlc
/usr/lib/vlc
/usr/share/vlc
$
```

although for this example, its a bit tricky since you have to know that the rpm package containing the binary it called vlc-core.

Answer (score 0):

For bash there is a builtin command called `type` which will tell you what a command/alias really is:

```
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ alias t=type
$ type t
t is aliased to `type'
$ type vlc
vlc is /bin/vlc
$
```